Cannot Access Resource Files from WEB-INF Directory
I added the JSP files in the WEB-INF/admin and WEB-INF/user directory. The images and other static files are added to the src/main/resources/static directory.
<img src="/src/main/resources/static/images/icon.png" alt="Logo">

After running the application, I got the view but the image wasn't loading. It only shows the alt text.
Here is the project folder structure
I configured the application.properties file like this:
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**

I also tried without the spring.mvc.static-path-pattern property.
Here, is the maven dependency related to the JSP that I've used:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>

I don't want to add the images to the WEB-INF directory. However, the IntelliJ IDEA does not give suggestions for the path to the files that are external directories of the WEB-INF directory. Since this is a Spring Boot project, I don't use any web artifacts and I build this project as a JAR.
I want to load the image files and the other static files that are located in the src/main/resources/static directory from the WEB-INF folder.
I have tried some other posts which ask the same question or relevant questions, but they didn't answer my problem.

There is no src/main/resources that is the root of the class path.
